# How can I use the getFieldElements from BootstrapValidator to select items outside the form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if is possible to use [getFieldElements](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/api/#get-field-elements)  to select items from any html tag outside the form. I have one hidden input with a ID value that I want to use as data to validate a remote (from BootstrapValidator). I can't figure out from documentation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getFieldElements` can be use get the input field by name.

```
validator.getFieldElements('input-name').val()
```